# Prolog Instantiation Error Issue

Tags: prolog

I've been getting an instantiation error in some prolog code I'm working on.

```
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

the error occurs when a predicate called connects calls linked to (hopefully) produce a list of children that are linked to a node (called Next).

I've tested linked and it seems to work fine on it's own it's just when it is called like this. I'm guessing it has something to do with the 'child' but I'm new to prolog so I'm not sure what exactly.

I have a second version of linked which works fine with connects but doesn't actually work by itself.

here is some of the code:

```
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A+1, D is B+1.
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A-1, D is B-1.
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A, D is B-1.
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A, D is B+1.
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A-1, D is B.
linked(loc(A, B), loc(C, D)) :- C is A+1, D is B.

connects(State, End, Colour, Next, Close) :- linked(Child, Next)
```

There is more to the program than this but through much debugging I have come to the conclusion that these lines are where the problems are occurring.

More info:
Connects is a predicate that is used in a predicate called connected that works out whether there is an unbroken path of same elements. 
Linked is a predicate that finds out if two nodes are next to each other (vertical, diagonal, horizontal. not in a square grid though, think hexagons).

here is an example state too

```
    [e,e,b,e,e],
   [e,w,w,b,e],
  [b,w,b,w,w],
 [w,w,b,b,b],
[e,e,b,w,e]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is yield because there is a variable on the right side of an `is`.

In `connects/5` you use `linked(Child,Next)`, but `Child` is nowhere else used, so always unbound. So when `linked/2` is called, `A` and `B` are always variables which results in the error.

Do you mean `linked(State,Next)`?

Comment: Hey thank you so much! While your answer didn't actually solve my problem it put me on the right path in terms of thinking. I just changed it to "linked(Next, Child)" and now it works! :D ...onto the next problem :P